# Inaccurate row count leading to bad query plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have somewhat of a puzzle here I'm hoping you can help with. Consider these two queries:

```
select bd.*, hc.Household
  into #BasketDetail
  from BasketDetail bd
  join #Product p on bd.Product = p.ProductId
  join #HouseholdCard hc on hc.Card = bd.Card
 where bd.TransactionDate between '2012-08-01' and '2012-08-31 23:59:59'
```

Query plan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc2xN.jpg

and

```
select bd.*, hc.Household
  into #BasketDetail
  from BasketDetail bd
  join #HouseholdCard hc on hc.Card = bd.Card
 where bd.TransactionDate between '2012-08-01' and '2012-08-31 23:59:59'
   and bd.product in (select productID from #Product)
```

Query plan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lauxz.jpg

They both attempt to create a temporary extract of a large table with transactions in it. The first one ran for over an hour before I killed it, the second one takes about a minute. The BasketDetail table is partitioned by month. Looking at the query plan, both are using the partitioning, but the first plan is seems to expect only 1 row and ends up using a bunch of nested loops as a result.

Any idea why switching from a join to an IN statement would have this effect? The tweak works fine when I don't need values from the product table, but that's not always the case. In that case, joining to the product table as well as using the in clause does the trick, but it is duplicative.

Comment: The queries are not equivalent unless you have a primari key or unique constraint on productid in #product. Try to add a primary key constraint on the temp table. I think it will improve both your queries and probably make the query plan identical.

Comment: An index (PK?) on card in #HouseholdCard would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Logically they are equivalent since productid is unique (though I don't have an explicit constraint). I tried adding a primary key constraint to #product and it didn't change the plan for either (other than switching from a table scan to an index scan when accessing Product). Same for #HouseholdCard. Any other ideas?